# Color for subsequent punctuations marks

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, hyperref, biber

I use the following code for coloring the brackets of the references in my text. This works fine also for the commas and hyphen in-between the brackets. However the colors for the subsequent punctuation marks are changed as well. Are there any solution that these punctuation marks appears in the standard text color?

Please note, for compiling the example bellow you maybe must change your default bibliography tool to Biber.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,chapterprefix=true,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[doi=false,url=true,isbn=false,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp,bibencoding=utf8,babel=other,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{CeruleanRef}{RGB}{12,127,172}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=CeruleanRef]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{bibname.bib}
@book{Lehner2014,
author = {Lehner, Markus and Tichler, Robert and Koppe, Markus},
doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-03995-4},
file = {:Users/lima/ICP/Literatur/Power-to-Gas- Technology and Business Models.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {978-3-319-03994-7},
title = {{Power-to-Gas: Technology and Business Models}},
year = {2014}
}
@article{Garcia2014,
author = {Garcia-Fresnillo, L. and Shemet, V. and Chyrkin, A. and de Haart, L.G.J. and Quadakkers, W.J.},
doi = {10.1016/j.jpowsour.2014.07.189},
file = {:Users/lima/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Garcia-Fresnillo et al. - 2014 - Long-term behaviour of solid oxide fuel cell interconnect materials in contact with Ni-mesh during e(2).pdf:pdf},
issn = {03787753},
journal = {J. Power Sources},
month = dec,
pages = {213--222},
publisher = {Elsevier B.V},
title = {{Long-term behaviour of solid oxide fuel cell interconnect materials in contact with Ni-mesh during exposure in simulated anode gas at 700 and 800}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0378775314012531},
volume = {271},
year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{bibname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\color{CeruleanRef}\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
 \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
    test
  \cite{Lehner2014} and \cite{Garcia2014} but \cite{Lehner2014}. Or \cite{Lehner2014,Garcia2014}, which has
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Your file doesn't compile to me due to the degree symbol in one of the references. Do you see any error of this kind that you maybe skip? In general, I get a **completely different output** from what you show us. But I do get colored punctuation, like you do.

Comment: A temporary solution might be to enclose the cite command inside a brace like {\cite{Lehner2014}}. This seem to remove the coloring of the punctuation next to it!

Comment: Ambikas temporary solutions work for me too. Unfortunately this is not practicable approach for a thesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own bracket command (or redefine \mkbibbrackets):

```
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibbracketscolor}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \color{CeruleanRef}\bibopenbracket#1\bibclosebracket%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbracketscolor]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
 \usebibmacro{postnote}}
```