# Text-color for subsequent punctuations/brackets

Tags: color

I use `xcolor`. I have this LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\blue#1 {\textcolor{blue} {#1} }
\def\red#1 {\textcolor{red} {#1} }

\begin{document}
foo (limited by \blue{A}, and \red{B}) bar
\end{document}
```

It will also color the subsequent punctuation comma `,` and closing bracket `)`.

I don't want that. How can I disable that?

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241184/color-for-subsequent-punctuations-marks?rq=1) might be related.

Comment: Now you have added a complete document but it does not have the problem that you are asking about! You have changed the definitions and are using the fixed versions. I'll edit so the answers make sense.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry for copying the wrong text. I should have tested it. There is no automatic way here on Tex.SE to compile&display the LaTeX code? That would have made it simpler, and also would be nice to directly see the result, for me and for other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\def\blue#1           {\textcolor{blue} {#1} }
```

defines `\blue` to be a macro with argument delimited by a space so in

```
  \blue{A}, and
```

`#1` is `{A},`

If you used

```
\newcommand\blue[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
```

it would work as you expect.

Comment: a closing curly bracket is missing at the end

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that what you wrote even works at all. Anyway, you can type `foo (limited by {\color{blue}A}, and {\color{magenta}B}) bar`.

Comment: just a comment to future readers: this was a correct answer to the original question (which did not show the broken definitions addressed in the other answers)